# Why the value of class is not displayed in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I want to display class value in  `<p></p>`

---

Why the value of class is not displayed?

```
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>

<script async src="bunnies.js"></script>
<script>
   let bunnies = new Bunnies();
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = bunnies;
    console.log(bunnies)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in bunnies.js:

```
class Bunnies{
    constructor() {
        this.sex = this.getGender()
    }
    getGender(){
        const sexArr = ['female', 'male'];
        let sex_rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*sexArr.length);
        return sexArr[sex_rand]
    }
}
```

Error in console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Bunnies is not defined
at bunies.html?_ijt=sqlvpt9vcg2qs0ns32n8e0it37:35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading `bunnies.js` with the [`async` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp), which means the next `<script>` may be executed before `bunnies.js` is loaded.

> If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing)

Try removing the `async` attribute and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove `async`  from the script tag or alternatively you can use `defer` in place of async in the html **script**  tag  make execution in order.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `async` in the `<script>` tag.